# Why are even pages empty?

Tags: books, page

I'm writing a mini-book for 12th grade students on physics, and I finished it (Finally) the only problem I have is that the even pages are blank when I move to another Chapter ! How can I solve this !

[image: The page isn't blank because I didn't stopped in an even page]
The page isn't blank because I didn't stopped in an even page

[image: The page 66 is blank, because the chapter stopped in an odd page (65)]
The page 66 is blank, because the chapter stopped in an odd page (65)

Comment: unrelated to your question but you should increase \headheight to 15pt as it says in the warning, also minipage does not have a `C`  option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to pass the `openany` option to the `book` document class:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

`book` defaults to starting new chapters on right (odd) pages, i.e. `openright`, but you can change this by passing `openany` (it's just the other way around for `report`, BTW).

See https://latexref.xyz/Document-class-options.html#Document-class-options , for instance.